# How do I configure SQL Server to allow access via IIS

Tags: sql-server, iis

I have a web service that stores data in a local SQL Server 2008 database. If I run the web service under my account the web service can successfully access the database. However, if  I use the DefaultAppPool (IUSR) account then accessing the database from the web service fails.

How do I set security on SQL Server to allow access to a specific database via IIS?

The specific error message I am getting is:
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'

Comment: What is the connection string in your web service?

Comment: It is an entity framework connection string, as follows:

    <add name="IVSUsageDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/IVSUsageDBModel.csdl|res://*/IVSUsageDBModel.ssdl|res://*/IVSUsageDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=BORIS\BORISSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=IVSUsageDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: For improved security you could create your web service within SQL Server itself by creating a HTTP Endpoint.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two options (obvious maybe!):

- Instead of using Windows Integrated
  Security use SQL Authentication
  instead.
- If you can't or don't want to, then you have
  to create a new user in SQL Server
  that relates to that Windows account.
- Or (third option) you can change the web service to run under an account that you know works.

Comment: +1. Agreed, use some kind of account (SQL or A.D.) that is specific to this application only. Put that account into a role, set the permissions on the role.

Answer (score 5):

I generally run the app pool under a domain user account, that way you control the specific user for each site on your server.

If I can't use a domain account, I'll run the site as "Network Service" - and the user that would correspond to that in SQL would be the machine account (MACHINENAME$ - replace "machinename" with your IIS server name").

If you plan to use the new IIS7 IIS users - which are not windows users - you'll have to use SQL Authentication instead of Windows authentication for your SQL database access.