# In CodeCharge Studio 4.3, i get a database error

Tags: codecharge

I made a page and a Login page to secure that first page. When you login, it show the error:
Unable to establish connection to database.
Error information:
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (0x80040E4D)
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.
Anyone know what this exactly means and what to do about it?
Answers help! :D

Answer (score 0):

Check your Connection string settings for your 'Design' and the 'Live' server (which might be your own PC with IIS installed)

You may be able to access the tables etc when in Design mode, but when you publish it (even locally) it will use the 'Live' server details - which will mean you need to check that IIS has an appropriate user to access the SQL Server and database.

Most of the time I use 'SQL Authentication', but either way you need to allow the user access to SQL and DB.

Have a look at these other questions for options:

[How do I configure SQL Server to allow access via IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064561/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-to-allow-access-via-iis)

and Microsoft has several options from this article:

[MSDN Accessing SQL Server from a Web Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht43wsex(v=vs.100).aspx)